# Trying to implement a loading spinner for React, but nothing seems to load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I currently have a parent component that makes an API call, and then passes that data down to mapped child components. I tried adding a spinner by following a few tutorials, but none seem to work. Nothing displays until the child component renders with the API data. Here's what I'm working with:

### Relevant Code

parent.jsx

```
class TweetList extends Component {
  state = {
    tweet_ids: [],
    loading: true,
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get(`https://apicall.com/recent/?format=json`)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ tweet_ids: res.data });
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }

render() {
    return (
          <div className="row">
            {/* plug in tweet component here */}
            {this.props.loading ? (
              <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
            ) : (
              this.state.tweet_ids.map((tweet) => (
                <Tweet
                  tweetId={tweet.id_str}
                  loading={this.state.loading}
                  key={this.props.tweetId}
                />
              ))
            )}
          </div>
    );
  }
}
```

child.jsx

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
        <TwitterTweetEmbed tweetId={this.props.tweetId} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Expected Output

Ideally, the value of `loading` is set to true at the start, so the spinning icon displays via the ternary. Once the API call is made and the data is received, `loading` is set to false, so the ternary should switch to rendering each child component. What's really happening is that the spinner doesn't display whatsoever, but the data does as usual once it loads.

### What I tried so far

1. Switched `this.setState({ loading: false });` to happen outside of the `.then` call. Same output.
2. Made the spinner loading happen in the child component, which although sounds great the child components wont load unless `tweet_ids` already has the fetched info.

If anyone has any idea what to do, I'd appreciate it, thank you.

Comment: A side note, you do not need to write 2 `setState` statements to set 2 properties. You may just do `this.setState({ loading:false, tweet_ids: res.data });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the loading variable in *state* & calling it in *props* *(this.props.loading)*.
Please update the conditional statement as

```
{this.state.loading ? (
      <Spinner animation="border" variant="primary" />
    ) : (
      <>
      this.state.tweet_ids.map((tweet) => (
        <Tweet
          tweetId={tweet.id_str}
          loading={this.state.loading}
          key={this.props.tweetId}
        />
      ))
     </>
    )}
```

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to change it from props to state. Thanks so much.